# How to change position of button JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

As you can see I have two buttons right now (button and button2) The problem is that they are in the center of JavaFX window (in the same place). So I don't see one of them because 2nd is covering 1st. What is wrong? The main objective of this simple app is to have two buttons on main screen. And after clicking into one of buttons, I expect to open new window with some other content.

```
public class Run extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

            Button button = new Button();
            button.setText("Navigation");
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    Label secondLabel = new Label("Select from list");

                    StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
                    secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);

                    Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 500, 400);

                    // New window (Stage)
                    Stage newWindow = new Stage();
                    newWindow.setTitle("Adding products");
                    newWindow.setScene(secondScene);

                    // Specifies the modality for new window.
                    newWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

                    // Specifies the owner Window (parent) for new window
                    newWindow.initOwner(primaryStage);

                    // Set position of second window, related to primary window.
                    newWindow.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 200);
                    newWindow.setY(primaryStage.getY() + 100);

                    newWindow.show();
                }
            });

            Button button2 = new Button();
            button2.setText("X");
            button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    Label secondLabel = new Label("Select from list");

                    StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
                    secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);

                    Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 500, 400);

                    // New window (Stage)
                    Stage newWindow = new Stage();
                    newWindow.setTitle("Adding products");
                    newWindow.setScene(secondScene);

                    // Specifies the modality for new window.
                    newWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

                    // Specifies the owner Window (parent) for new window
                    newWindow.initOwner(primaryStage);

                    // Set position of second window, related to primary window.
                    newWindow.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 200);
                    newWindow.setY(primaryStage.getY() + 100);

                    newWindow.show();
                }
            });

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(button);
            root.getChildren().add(button2);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 450);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Shopping Buddy");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is the expected behavior since you are using `StackPane`. Try to use a different pane, like `HBox`.

Comment: More generally, see the [layout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).